# Python - get all index from another list

Tags: python

I`m trying to append an list of the indexes of another list.

I have one list with random numbers, and need to create another list, with the indexes of the first list.

My code is just like this:

```
from random import seed
from random import randint
seed(715)
g1 = []
g2 = []
for v in range(20328):
valor = randint(40, 220)
g1.append(valor)


for v in enumerate(g1):
    g2.append(v)

print("v g1[v] g2[v] g1[g2[v]]")
for v in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:
    print(v, g1[v], g2[v], g1[g2[v]])
```

But I get the error below:

```
print(v, g1[v], g2[v], g1[g2[v]])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Because g2 list contains tuples due to enumerate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using enumerate to fill g2 with tuples, enumarate will give you the index and the value as a tuple, so whenever you call g2[v], you won't get the index only, you will get a tuple of (index, value). If you want the index only in g2, you should use something like the following the create g2.

```
for i, v in enumerate(g1):
    g2.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

g2 is set as a list of tuples in your program, not integers. If you use `print(g2[0])` to see what's inside you'll get something like `g2[0]:(0, 69)` which is a tuple. So that's the problem.

You can use any of the following to resolve the issue:

```
for v in enumerate(g1):
    g2.append(v[1])
```

or

```
for index, value in enumerate(g1):
    g2.append(value)
```

or

```
for value in g1:
    g2.append(value)
```

Helpful resource:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 0):

Like Sandeep Kadapa said, g2 gets turned into a tuple, so try to do something like,

```
list(g2)
```

after the enumerate and before the print functions are called.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add only indexes to the second list?

```
for index, v in enumerate(g1):
    g2.append(index)
```

Btw I would replace that function with something like that:

```
g2 = list(range(len(g1))
```

Let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate in your code sets `v` as a tuple. You produce the index and the element with the following format:

```
for count, v in enumerate(g1):
    g2.append(count)
```

where `count` will be the index of `g1`, and `v` will be the element at that index.